# How to connect React App to my API (using Elastic Search UI template)

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, api, elasticsearch

I am new to the field of front end programming and need some advice. I am trying to build a website for a search application. For this purpose, I am using the Elastic Search UI (find documentation here: https://github.com/elastic/search-ui). The Elastic Search UI provides the layouts and some technical usage, that is helpful for search requests.

I have been starting by understanding the given example page about national parks. The code looks as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";

import AppSearchAPIConnector from "@elastic/search-ui-app-search-connector";

import {
  ErrorBoundary,
  Facet,
  SearchProvider,
  SearchBox,
  Results,
  PagingInfo,
  ResultsPerPage,
  Paging,
  Sorting,
  WithSearch
} from "@elastic/react-search-ui";
import {
  BooleanFacet,
  Layout,
  SingleSelectFacet,
  SingleLinksFacet
} from "@elastic/react-search-ui-views";
import "@elastic/react-search-ui-views/lib/styles/styles.css";

const SORT_OPTIONS = [
  {
    name: "Relevance",
    value: "",
    direction: ""
  },
  {
    name: "Title",
    value: "title",
    direction: "asc"
  }
];

const connector = new AppSearchAPIConnector({
  searchKey: "search-371auk61r2bwqtdzocdgutmg",
  engineName: "search-ui-examples",
  hostIdentifier: "host-2376rb",
  endpointBase: ""
});

const config = {
  alwaysSearchOnInitialLoad: true,
  searchQuery: {
    result_fields: {
      title: {
        snippet: {
          size: 100,
          fallback: true
        }
      },
      nps_link: {
        raw: {}
      },
      description: {
        snippet: {
          size: 100, // size of the description field, i.e. the text displayed
          fallback: true
        }
      }
    },
    disjunctiveFacets: ["acres", "states", "date_established", "location"],
    facets: {
      world_heritage_site: { type: "value" },
      states: { type: "value", size: 30 },
      acres: {
        type: "range",
        ranges: [
          { from: -1, name: "Any" },
          { from: 0, to: 1000, name: "Small" },
          { from: 1001, to: 100000, name: "Medium" },
          { from: 100001, name: "Large" }
        ]
      },
      location: {
        // San Francisco. In the future, make this the user's current position
        center: "37.7749, -122.4194",
        type: "range",
        unit: "mi",
        ranges: [
          { from: 0, to: 100, name: "Nearby" },
          { from: 100, to: 500, name: "A longer drive" },
          { from: 500, name: "Perhaps fly?" }
        ]
      },
      date_established: {
        type: "range",

        ranges: [
          {
            from: moment()
              .subtract(50, "years")
              .toISOString(),
            name: "Within the last 50 years"
          },
          {
            from: moment()
              .subtract(100, "years")
              .toISOString(),
            to: moment()
              .subtract(50, "years")
              .toISOString(),
            name: "50 - 100 years ago"
          },
          {
            to: moment()
              .subtract(100, "years")
              .toISOString(),
            name: "More than 100 years ago"
          }
        ]
      },
      visitors: {
        type: "range",
        ranges: [
          { from: 0, to: 10000, name: "0 - 10000" },
          { from: 10001, to: 100000, name: "10001 - 100000" },
          { from: 100001, to: 500000, name: "100001 - 500000" },
          { from: 500001, to: 1000000, name: "500001 - 1000000" },
          { from: 1000001, to: 5000000, name: "1000001 - 5000000" },
          { from: 5000001, to: 10000000, name: "5000001 - 10000000" },
          { from: 10000001, name: "10000001+" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  apiConnector: connector
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SearchProvider config={config}>
      <WithSearch mapContextToProps={({ wasSearched }) => ({ wasSearched })}>
        {({ wasSearched }) => {
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <ErrorBoundary>
                <Layout
                  header={
                    <SearchBox
                    />
                  }
                  sideContent={
                    <div>
                      {wasSearched && (
                        <Sorting label={"Sort by"} sortOptions={SORT_OPTIONS} />
                      )}
                      <Facet
                        field="states"
                        label="States"
                        filterType="any"
                        isFilterable={true}
                      />
                      <Facet
                        field="world_heritage_site"
                        label="World Heritage Site?"
                        view={BooleanFacet}
                      />
                      <Facet
                        field="visitors"
                        label="Visitors"
                        view={SingleLinksFacet}
                      />
                      <Facet
                        field="date_established"
                        label="Date Established"
                        filterType="any"
                      />
                      <Facet
                        field="location"
                        label="Distance"
                        filterType="any"
                      />
                      <Facet
                        field="acres"
                        label="Acres"
                        view={SingleSelectFacet}
                      />
                    </div>
                  }
                  bodyContent={
                    <Results
                      titleField="title"
                      urlField="nps_link"
                      shouldTrackClickThrough={true}
                    />
                  }
                  bodyHeader={
                    <React.Fragment>
                      {wasSearched && <PagingInfo />}
                      {wasSearched && <ResultsPerPage />}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  }
                  bodyFooter={<Paging />}
                />
              </ErrorBoundary>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </WithSearch>
    </SearchProvider>
  );
}
```

The example page can be seen here:

https://search-ui-stable.netlify.app/

I understand most of the code and how to modify the search components for my needs. Now I want to "upload" my own data. From what I am understanding, I have to do this over an API. I have already written one, that takes some input query (i.e. the search request) and outputs a json file. My question is now: How can I "extract" the search query and pass it to my API and as a result show the results, which should be the output of my API?

I think, I have to add some code here:

```
<WithSearch mapContextToProps={({ wasSearched }) => ({ wasSearched })}>
            {({ wasSearched }) => {
```

But I am not quite sure what to do. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps for somebody you have to make the difference between ElasticSearch and AppSearch (Elasticsearch product)

search-ui works by default with AppSearch. If you want to connect Elasticsearch directly you have to build a custom connector.

You can use this example though:
https://github.com/elastic/search-ui/tree/master/examples/elasticsearch

Live Demo
https://search-ui-stable-elasticsearch.netlify.com/

Regards